# How to determine convergence of series?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

I was having some trouble with this series and finding its convergence interval. How should I go about doing it?

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{\frac{(x+1)^n}{2^n }}$$

Attempts:
I know that I can rewrite it as: 
$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\left(\frac{x+1}{2}\right)^n$

And from other problems I've done, I know this is a geometric sequence. I haven't learned the ratio test yet, and I'm just wondering how I should do this.

Comment: 0.  Welcome  1.  Learn Mathjax.  2.  see "How to ask a good question" in the FAQ.   3.  Ratio test

Comment: I'm sorry, but you don't have to be so rude

Comment: @johnners17 Our site gets a lot of questions like this: just the question, without any effort shown. If you could try using the ratio test, the feedback for your question will be much better.

Comment: @TobyMak I showed my attempt

Comment: You're right, it's geometric.  The main result tells you when such a thing converges (absolute value of ratio below $1$), so work out the $x$s that make that result hold.

Answer (score 1):

A geometric series $\sum_{n=0}^\infty r^n$ converges if and only if $|r|<1$.

Hence, for your problem, the value of $x$ where it converges satisfies $$\left|\frac{x+1}2 \right| < 1.$$

Try to solve the inequality.